# How to merge multiple data frame into one table and export to Excel?

Tags: r, excel

I would like to merge a few data frame into one table, and export to Excel. data frame is generated as below.

```
sex <- c("male","female")
count1 <- c(304,410)
df.sex <- data.frame(sex,count1)
df.sex[,"per"] <- df.sex$count1/sum(df.sex$count1)

agegp <- c("<=24","25-29","30-34","35-39")
count2 <- c(204,250,125,135)
df.agegp <- data.frame(agegp,count2)
df.agegp[,"per"] <- df.agegp$count2/sum(df.agegp$count2)

df.sex
sex count1       per
male    304 0.4257703
female    410 0.5742297

df.agegp
agegp count2       per
<=24    204 0.2857143
25-29    250 0.3501401
30-34    125 0.1750700
35-39    135 0.1890756
```

Since the first column of the two df are different, I could not rbind them and export to Excel.

What I would like to generate is a table like below and export it to Excel.

Can anyone help?

```
       count    percentage
sex     
male    304     0.4257703
female  410     0.5742297
agegp       
<=24    204     0.2857143
25-29   250     0.3501401
30-34   125     0.1750700
35-39   135     0.1890756
```

Comment: Your best strategy is to export the two df separately to csv using `write.csv` and then merge in excel. Merging this kind of data in R is a mess.

Comment: I previously export them to excel, putting the two df in separate sheets. Do you mean export to two different csv file? Or is it possible to export to one csv file, just by adding the second df right under the first df in the same sheet? My main purpose here is to export to the same sheet. Thank you

Comment: just look into join() from dplyr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that ?

```
sink(file = "mergedPrinting.csv")

cat("First Frame:\n") 
write.csv(df.agegp, row.names = F)

cat("--------\n")

cat("Second Frame:\n")
write.csv(df.sex, row.names = F)

sink()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two EXCEL import/export R-packages I know of, both let you define the top left cell in which to begin writing your data.frame and wether to use a header.

- [XLConnect](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html)
- [xlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html)

In your case I'd write the labels, count, percentage, sex, agegp, as single values into the cells and then write the two data.frames with rownames but no columnnames to the right position.

See the vignette of both packages on how to open/create an EXCEL-file for writing and for the functions to write data.frames.