# Exporting two data frames into same file

Tags: r, csv, append, export

I currently have two data-frames, One DF contains around ~100,000 rows, while the other only has ~1000. I can export either one of these using the write.table function shown below...

```
 write.table(DF_1, file = paste("DF_one.csv" ),
        row.names = F, col.names = T, sep = ",")
```

This is easily opened by excel and works well. The problem is I need to include the other data frame in the very same excel file, and I'm not sure how to do this or if it is even possible.

I am open to any ideas, and have provided some example data to work with below.

```
#Example data for data frame one, length =30
Dates<-c(Sys.Date()+1:30)
Data1<-c(1+1:30)

#Data Frame One
Df1<-data.frame(Dates,Data1)

#Example data for data rame two, length=10
Letters<-c(letters[1:10])
Data2<-c(1:10)

#Data Frame Two
Df2<-data.frame(Letters,Data2)

#Now, is there a way can we export both to the same file? 

#Here is the export for just data frame one
write.table(Df1, file = paste("DFone.csv" ),
        row.names = F, col.names = T, sep = ",")
```

Any ideas including:"stop being picky and just export 2 files and then merge in excel" are appreciated.

Research Done:

I like this approach but would prefer a horizontal format instead of vertical
(I should probably just not be picky)

[How to merge multiple data frame into one table and export to Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038041/how-to-merge-multiple-data-frame-into-one-table-and-export-to-excel)

[How to write multiple tables, dataframes, regression results etc - to one excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444277/how-to-write-multiple-tables-dataframes-regression-results-etc-to-one-excel)

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you show `dput(head(df1))` and `dput(head(df2))`? And also show how your desired output looks like.

Comment: If by "horizontal format" you mean that you want to append columns to an existing csv, then you can't do that and this has nothing to do with R but rather the way csv is stored in desk.

Comment: @Ala possibly, I am just trying to basically show two data frames in the same excel file, formatted so that they are next to each other rather than one on top of the other. Again not sure if this is possible at all...

Comment: @Masoud well the user who had a somewhat correct answer deleted theirs, so would you mind putting that just using an append=T on both of the export commands will allow them to be exported, preserving format to the same file. I would like to mark this question as answered

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean but you can post an answer to your question. Based on your question (seeking "horizontal appending", did I just made up that term?) that answer wasn't the right one. You can answer your question and after a day you'll be able to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Gotcha..Yes unfortunately the horizontal appending did not happen, I think I will just manually do this once in excel.  The most important element was that all the data be in excel be in one file and be in its' respective df.  I guess I will keep this open, maybe someone will be able to do this eventually. Until then the horizontal appending will have to be done manually. I see a package opportunity!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this preserves the information structure that you want but you are really intent on getting them into the same table you could do the following.

```
Both <- data.frame(Df1,Df2)

write.table(Both, file = paste("DF_Both.csv" ),
    row.names = F, col.names = T, sep = ",")
```

Because the first solution did not meet your requirements here is another one that saves data frames to multiple tabs of an excel spreadsheet.

```
install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)

###Define the save.xlsx function

save.xlsx <- function (file, ...)
{
  require(xlsx, quietly = TRUE)
  objects <- list(...)
  fargs <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))
  objnames <- as.character(fargs)[-c(1, 2)]
  nobjects <- length(objects)
  for (i in 1:nobjects) {
    if (i == 1)
      write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i])
    else write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i],
                    append = TRUE)
  }
  print(paste("Workbook", file, "has", nobjects, "worksheets."))
}

### Save the file to your working directory.

save.xlsx("WorkbookTitle.xlsx", Df1, Df2)
```

Full discolsure this was adapted from another question on stack overflow [R dataframes to multi sheet Excel Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743294/r-dataframes-to-multi-sheet-excel-work)

Comment: I wish programming was this simple. Don't you think you cannot do `data.frame(df1,df2)` because they are not the same size (number of rows)?

Comment: @Masoud is right, the data frames cannot be merged due to differences in length, Thank you for the help though nevertheless

Comment: It was by luck that the number of rows in Df1 is a multiplication of the number of rows in Df2 in the provided example. But this won't generalize.

Comment: @Ala there is `~` behind each of those numbers. They are not multiplication of each other when they are not exact numbers. Even in that case. OP doesn't want to write the `df2` 10 times beside the `df1`.